# Add attribute in project using codeFirst and DbFirst at same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a project managed with CodeFirst and DbFirst(edmx) and i need to add a new attribute in a table.
When adding it with migration it reveals Entity problems and when adding it with DbFirst, migration cannot be passed due to existence of the field. What can i do ?

The error below is after passing migration and updating edmx File. 'TopActive' is the attribute that i added to model.
And the error with CodeFirst is that the field already exist in Db.

```
        Message "The specified type member 'TopActive' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."    string
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO3al.png)

Comment: could you add the entities (what is working, what you want to add) and exact error for codefirst?

Comment: have a look at my answer

Comment: @GabrielLlorico I added the error that i faced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using :
1- CodeFirst Migrations 
2- Edit the edmx manually by adding the attribute in XML and without refreshing the edmx.

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be a little tedious.

First would be create a new property with the attribute you desire

```
//example
public class EntityA
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Property {get; set;} //Property you want to add [attribute] but not working

    [AttributeYouWantToAdd]
    public string PropertyWithAttribute {get; set;}
}
```

Second, build the migration. In your migration, add this after your `AddColumn`

```
Sql("Update Table Set PropertyWithAttribute = Property");
```

Third, drop previous property, add migration again.

Fourth, add the Property again with proper name and attribute then add migration again.

Then same, after the `AddColumn`

```
Sql("Update Table Set Property = PropertyWithAttribute")
```

then drop `PropertyWithAttribute`, add migration

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll try it

Comment: @essimo if it will answer your question, can you mark it as answer? Thanks

Comment: Please could you explain your solution more, cause the problem that i faced is that i can't add the property using the two approaches DbFirst and CodeFirst at same time